# Only one JSF form is it necessary?

Tags: java, jsf, webforms, jsf-2

I have some input in my page to submit a subscription and a h:dataTable.
My doubt its necessary one h:form for the inputs and another for the dataTable, or only one containing both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to submit the elements together you can put them inside the same `h:form`.

If the `h:dataTable` doesn't contain input elements you don't need to put it inside a form.